# Orthonormal axes with 3D Surface in Plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I didn't succeed to use `scaleanchor` for Surface plot in Plotly:

```
x = np.linspace(0,9,100)
y = np.linspace(0,3,100)

mx, my = np.meshgrid(x,y)
mz = np.sin(my) * np.cos(mx)

trace = go.Surface(x=mx, y=my, z=mz)
layout = go.Layout( 
    yaxis={'scaleanchor':'x'},
    # zaxis={'scaleanchor':'x'},
)
py.iplot([trace], layout)
```

[image]
Two issues:

- `zaxis` is not allowed in Layout
- `yaxis={'scaleanchor':'x'}` has no effect, a cube from the top is not a square. Here is the result I want from the top (1 has same length in x and in y):

[image]

done with

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
plt.axes().set_aspect('equal', 'datalim')
plt.contour(mx, my, mz)
```

Any idea how to see a cube as a cube and any shape as it is in 3D graphics with Plotly?

Olivier.

Comment: this [example](https://plot.ly/python/3d-mesh/#mesh-cube) from docs did not what you trying to achieved?

Comment: In this example we have orthonormal axes indeed but this is due to the data provided. If you change values like `x = [0, 0, 10, 10, 0, 0, 10, 10]` then the result still looks like a cube even if the shape is not anymore a cube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the trick:

```
layout = go.Layout( 
    scene = {'aspectmode':'data'},
)

trace = go.Surface(x=mx, y=my, z=mz)
fig = go.Figure(data=[trace], layout=layout)
py.iplot(fig)
```

And here is the result:

[image]